# Powerapps time values reflecting incorrectly (often just set to default) when adding or pulling from a Sharepoint List of Date and Time values

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I have a list in Sharepoint that includes the following snippet:

[image]

When I use a gallery in Powerapps, and link this list to it, the date and time display shows a different value for the time. For example, entry number 1's date and time look like this: 07/01/2022 19:40.

So the date has been converted to something else.

I don't know how to address it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Good question!

Sharepoint actually saves your times in UTC. This means that once PowerApps loads that time and corrects it to your time zone, the date and time could be different.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/jj164700%28v%3doffice.15%29

Basically, you take the UTC time and add your local time difference, that gives you the correct one :)